# How to determine XML type in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, types, casting

I'm writing a script that is supposed to look at the content of a file and determine if it is a (well formed) XML or not. I found a page on [ss64.com][1] that this is quite easy to do:

```
>32 -is [int]
True
```

The thing is however that I can only test this by casting the left-side for XML files:

```
>[xml](Get-Content c:\Path\To\xml_file.xml) -is [xml]
False
```

...which in this case would be rather pointless: if the file is XML, the casting will already prove this, else throw an exception. I therefore wonder: is there any way to determine XML files in Powershell in a True-False way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the `-as` operator:

```
[bool]((Get-Content c:\Path\To\xml_file.xml) -as [xml])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Is-Valid-XML 
{
    param ([string] $path)

    $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    try 
    {
        $xml.Load($path)
        $valid = $true
    }

    catch
    {
        $valid = $false
    }

    return $valid
}
```